# Javascript: Changing an image on click and then back to original when clicked again

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have been looking around and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I have tried a few solutions suggested on other posts which have not worked in my favor.

The title pretty much sums up what I am trying to accomplish, If you need more information leave a comment asking for what you would like to know.

The main part of this code I want to get working is the myFunction, the rest are examples I made so that people can better understand my thought process, here is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var demoStyle = document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundImage;
    var blue = "url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg)";
    var red = "url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-coral-fabric_smaller.jpg)";
    var x = (demoStyle == blue);

    if (demoStyle == blue) {
        demoStyle = blue;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Should have turned Blue";
        alert('Is the document Blue? Javascript says: ' + x + '.');
    } else {
        demoStyle = red;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Should have turned Red";
        alert('Is the document Red? Javascript says: ' + x + '.');
    }
}

function myFunction_NoVars() {
    if (document.getElementById("demoNoVars").style.backgroundImage == "url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg)") {
        document.getElementById("demoNoVars").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg)";
        document.getElementById("demoNoVars").innerHTML = "Should have turned Blue";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demoNoVars").style.backgroundImage == "url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-coral-fabric_smaller.jpg)"
        document.getElementById("demoNoVars").innerHTML = "Should have turned Red";
    }
}

function my_2nd_Function() {
    document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-coral-fabric_smaller.jpg)";
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Should have turned Red";
}
```

```css
div {text-align:center;padding:5px;height:100px;width:100px;background-image:url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg);}
button {margin-top:10px;padding:5px;min-width:50px;}
h2 {margin:0;padding:0;}
hr {margin-bottom:10px;padding:0;}
```

```html
<h2>Has Errors:</h2><hr />
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Run</button>
<br /><br />
    <div id="demoNoVars"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction_NoVars()">Run w/ No Variables</button>
<br /><br />
<h2>Doesn't Have Errors:</h2><hr />
    <div id="demo2"></div>
    <button onclick="my_2nd_Function()">Run</button>
    <p><strong>NOTE:</strong> This one changes, but I'm trying to create something that will change between the two every time the button is clicked.</p>
```

There is also a live preview [here](http://www.paymaster.net/net3/test/10/), JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nfLegmem/).
Thank you for any help.

Comment: css classes make this so much easier....

Comment: @epascarello I see based off your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for all that code. All you need to two CSS rules and to toggle a class name. The one CSS rule has the one image and the other rule has the other. You add the class and the second image appears.

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById(this.dataset.for).classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
```

```css
div.x {
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  background-image:url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg);
}
div.x.active {
  background-image: url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-coral-fabric_smaller.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="x" id="demo"></div>
<button data-for="demo">Run</button>

<div class="x" id="demo2"></div>
<button data-for="demo2">Run</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have gone through everyones answers and they are all great solutions. I have chosen to make your answer my solution because it seems like my cup of tea. appreciate your time.

Comment: Hello again, the code works great in the snippet but when I brought it to my environment i'm having an issue with the following line ` document.getElementById(this.dataset.for).classList.toggle("active"); `. My console is stating "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null(…)". Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind about the above, I found a work around. I posted it down below.

Comment: Well did you change the data-for attribute to be the id of the class?

Comment: I just dragged the code as it is into a new .aspx and saved it to see if I code get the example working in a document and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery, this is simple example, you can replace the background color to image

```js
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "change" );
});
```

```css
#box{
  background-color:red;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}

#box.change{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class=""></div>
```

Comment: Although this is a great answer I am not a fan of jQuery. Thank you for your response. +1

Answer (score 0):

The first function doesn't set the background image. So it's not surprising it isn't changing. The second function checks if it's blue and if so, sets it to blue. The second function doesn't change it, it simply confirms existing state.

```
if (document.getElementById("demoNoVars").style.backgroundImage == "url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg)") {
    document.getElementById("demoNoVars").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg)";
```

has the same url so nothing changes.

You should be swapping your if conditions in the second function and the first function should be setting the background.

Comment: So it's not saying " IF demoNoVars is equal to the value URL". I might be misunderstanding your point but I was thinking that two == is checking if the value matches and one = is setting the value.

Comment: your code reads "IF backgroundImage == 'x' THEN backgroundImage = 'x'. You instead want "IF backgroundImage == 'x' THEN backgroundImage = 'y'.

Comment: Ah ok I see now, Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple script, I've used a data-attribute to store you second image, I grab these into an array and rotate.

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');

[].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(function (f) {
  var im = [ f.getAttribute("src"), f.getAttribute("data-src2") ];
  f.onclick = function () {
    var k = im.shift(1); im.push(k);
    f.setAttribute("src", im[0]);
  };
});
```

```html
<img src="http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg"
     data-src2="http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-coral-fabric_smaller.jpg">
<img src="http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg"
     data-src2="http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-coral-fabric_smaller.jpg">
<img src="http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg"
     data-src2="http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-coral-fabric_smaller.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you, I have thumbed up your response this is a great answer and works flawlessly. I am selecting @epascrarello answer because it is more my style. I do appreciate your time and answer. (Unless you can select more than one answer because technically they all work, and they are answers)

Comment: This is an overly complicated answer to a simple problem. Readability is low and you don't really explain why the asker's original code wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few issues when moving some of these answers to my environment, but using them to do more research I found something that worked for me.

I want to post the solution here just incase someone comes across this question and the other solutions didn't work in their environments either.

Here is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    if (x.className.indexOf("red") == -1) {
        x.className = x.className.replace("blue", " red");
    } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace("red", " blue");
    }
}
```

```css
.blue {
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    background-image:url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-turquoise-fabric_smaller.jpg);
}
.red {
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    background-image: url(http://www.babybedding.com/images/fabric/solid-coral-fabric_smaller.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="blue"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" >Button</button>
```

Thanks everyone for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = document.getElementById("image1");
let state = false;

function transition() {
  x.src = state ? "image.jpg" : "image2.jpg";
  state = !state;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <img src="image.jpg" id="image1" onclick="transition()">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```