# Changing onclick back to original image when clicked a second time

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

I am trying to make a menu where there is an arrow pointing down sliding the menu down. What I want to do is change the image to an arrow pointing up when clicked. This I accomplished using onclick. However, I want to change the image back to an arrow pointing down upon being clicked again. I have tried a ton of different codes with both jQuery, css and html, and nothing have so far worked.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
   </script>
```

This is the jQuery, found this on w3schools. This is for toggling down the menu.

```
 <div id="menu" class="m1">

<div id="flip" >

<img src="pic/aroowdown.png" width="32" height="32" onclick="this.src='pic/aroowup.png'" />


</div>
<div id="panel">

<ul>
    <li><a href="epi.hmtl"> EPISODER </a></li>
    <li><a href="kar.html"> KARAKTERER </a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"> OM OSS </a></li>
    <li><a href="prod"> PRODUKSJON <a></li>
</ul>

</div>


</div>
```

This is the "flip" and "panel", where you can see that I use the "onClick".

I'm also gonna add the CSS for the flip and panel, just in case. I dont think it has much to do with my question tho.

```
#panel, #flip {

    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#panel {
    padding: 80px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    opacity: 0.9;


}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 30px;
}
```

Hope someone will know the answer to this! I know there is questions like this on this site, but none of those worked for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your arrows are just images, so you should be able to use the answer to [Javascript: Changing an image on click and then back to original when clicked again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097018/javascript-changing-an-image-on-click-and-then-back-to-original-when-clicked-ag?rq=1)